# Extract lines from rdd based on regex

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a file with data like below:

```
Samples of data observed from students of bio tech class

abc xyz are the representatives

description line1

descriptive line 2

..

descriptive line3

they have 79 students in the class

Class student list :

1 abc 23 m

2 def 22 m

3 xys 23 m
```

I want to extract lines starting from "abc" (2nd line) till "they have 79 students in the class" to another RDD

Output should be look like:

```
abc xyz are the representatives

description line1

descriptive line 2

..

descriptive line3

they have 79 students in the class
```

This is the code I have been trying to play with

```
val st_pattern1= """(abc).*?(?=\bthey have 79 students in the> class\b)""".r 
val test = sc.textFile("filname.txt") 
.map(lines => st_pattern1.findFirstIn(lines)) 
.foreach(println)
```

It is printing like below

```
none

none

none

..

..

none
```

I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong. Basically new to scala/spark. 
Can you help me on how to extract those line alone to an RDD.

Comment: One approach that you can take is :
val textFile = sc.textFile("filname.txt").collect.mkString(" ")

val st_pattern1= """(abc).*?(?=\bthey have 79 students in the> class\b)""".r 

val result=st_pattern1.findFirstIn(textFile)

println("result")

Comment: But this is not a good approach for big Data ! Try to change your file first to tag the data that needs to be extracted and then extract the Tagged data !

Comment: You're wanting a single linear operation (start *here* do stuff until *here*) using Spark, a system meant for operating on subsets of data in parallel. It's not going to work. Just do this outside of Spark

Comment: your file can be loaded across multiple nodes/partitions in case of huge file. so you have possibility of not getting expected result.

Comment: Thank You @Shivansh Srivastava. It works. But it return all the content in one line. I tried to split hem back to back to the line format the way they were originally. But no luck. What I have tried here is "val textFile = sc.textFile("filname.txt").collect.mkString(" abcedf ")   .val result =st_pattern1 findFirstIn(test)     abcedf is inserted within that content wherever line break was there. Then I tried to replace all the "abcedf" with new line character after applying the pattern like    val cd = result.replaceAll("abcedf", "\\n"). But it gives "is not a member of Option". any help?

Comment: In that Case Use This : 
 val textFile = sc.textFile("filname.txt").collect.mkString("~") val st_pattern1= """(abc).*?(?=\bthey have 79 students in the> class\b)""".r val result=st_pattern1.findFirstIn(textFile) println("result.split("~").mkString("\n")")

Comment: Thank You @Shivansh Srivastava. println(result.split("~").mkString("\n")) Using this , I got an error like "Value split is not member of Option[String]." So I modified it slightly like "val res = result.mkString
       .replaceAll("~", "\n")  println(res). " I tworked the way I wanted it. Thank you for you help on this. I learned few useful things with your answer.

Comment: @Theeban Good to know it works for you :) But Still I would say , Spark is not the best tool for this !